# How to evaluate $\int_C (x+y)^2dx - (x^2+y^2)dy$ over a triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Could someone help me to evaluate
$$\int_C (x+y)^2dx - (x^2+y^2)dy$$ where C is the positively oriented triangle with vertices at (1,1), (3,2) and (2,5)?

I tried to use Green's theorem to solve it and I got $\iint_D (-4x+2y) dA$  and I have no idea that what should I do next step.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\iint_D (-4x+2y) dA$ by setting it as a double integration?

Comment: Do you know about center of mass or centroid as a double integral? You can recognize $\iint_D x\,dA$ as $\bar x\cdot\text{area}(D)$ and $\iint_D y\,dA$ as $\bar y\cdot\text{area}(D)$. You can find the area and the centroid by more elementary means.

Comment: @ArcticChar yes I know, but it seens it will be very complex if I do it with setting the boundary and do integral twice, and I'm not sure this way is correct or not.

Comment: @TedShifrin your comment remind me that maybe I can use the formula of centroid $$(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3},\frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3})$$ to find out the centroid and do integral, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your integrand is not correct.

$Pdx + Qdy = (x+y)^2dx - (x^2+y^2)dy$

So, $P = (x+y)^2, Q = -(x^2+y^2)$

$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = -2x, \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 2x + 2y$

$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = -4x - 2y$

Now your region is positively oriented triangle with vertices $(1, 1), (3,2)$ and $(2, 5)$. Here is a sketch of your region -

[image]

Taking two points at a time, you can find the equations of lines that form this triangle. It is clear from the sketch that you have to either do a change of variable or just split your integral into two parts.

For integrating first over $y$ and then over $x$, your bounds for two integrals become $\frac{x + 1} {2} \leq y \leq (4x-3), 1 \leq x \leq 2$ and $\frac{x + 1} {2} \leq y \leq (11-3x), 2 \leq x \leq 3$

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that! Thank you for your correction!